# Complex/real base vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

If I have a subspace of $\mathbb C^n$ which is spanned by $N$ complex basis vectors. Could I span the same space with $N$ basis vectors that each have real components? (but, of course, using complex coefficients)?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Is your space supposed to be a subspace of $\mathbb C^k$ for some $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$.
Now consider the subspace spanned by $\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
i
\end{array}\right]$. That is, $$\text{span}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
i
\end{array}\right]\right)=\left\{ \left(z\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
i
\end{array}\right]\right)\in\mathbb{C}^{2}\mid z\in\mathbb{C}\right\}. $$ Clearly $\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
i
\end{array}\right]$ is in this space. Can you find a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ s.t.
$zv=\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
i
\end{array}\right]$ for some $z\in\mathbb{C}$? Try
and convince yourself that you cannot.

Comment: Thank you... My doubt was resolved.